# Breadcrumbs Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, product, category, breadcrumbs, megamenu

I have a problem with bread crumbs. I have several products that are in multiple different categories.

instead on the frontend side, univocal bread crumbs should appear (like the univocal path that the customer takes to get to that product - despite being the same product).

As you can see, the bread crumbs do not respect the unique path that that product makes (category x - subcategory x - product X). instead the product url is right.

the bread crumb should also be the same. instead everything behaves without a logical thread.

I don't understand which rule manages it all. it is as if one category dominates another.

what do you think it can depend on? thank you very much and I apologize if I have not explained myself well.

I tried to disable both the megamenu and the Porto theme.

Comment: Can you explain What you need in breadcrumb , and what you get .By default breadcrumb manage  home  > parent Category > child Category > product. in some case it only show home > product .

Answer (score 0):

You must follow in your admin, `Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use Categories Path for Product URLs`, you must change to **No**, and you have to make sure that in the **Website** and **Store View** is **No**.

After that, you must reindex and refresh the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Is your URLs same for product page irrespective of the navigation followed by a user while reaching your product page( if category is not in your URL then this will be the case
).
If yes then as Product page is generally cached so varnish will deliver same version for same URL.

Way out is to load Bread crumb via lazy loading( Ajax based ).
This will do both:

1. Use Full page cache and
2. You have the bread crumb as per visitor navigation path.

So check following :

1. Full page cache and its impact and how to resolve.
2. Theme : some themes handle this
3. Else allow category URL with product page( apply canonical URL to avoid duplicate content SEO penalty)